# Проверка введенных данных в функции

Tags: c, ввод, проверка

Не стоит обращать внимания на то, что никакого смысла код не несет - это всего лишь обрывок, подогнанный для того, чтоб сузить все вокруг проблемы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int foxes = 8;

void OutputField(char fieldForOutput[][8]) {    //вывод поля в консоль
    printf ("\n   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |\n");    //нумерация столбцов
    printf ("------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("\n%3d|",i+1);   //нумерация строк
        for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
                printf("%2c |", fieldForOutput[i][j]);
        printf("\n------------------------------------");
    }
}

int InputSteps(char fieldForOutput[][8]) {  //функция самой игры

    OutputField(fieldForOutput);
    int coordinatesRow, coordinatesCol, //координаты
    i, j, foxesOnTheLine = 0;       //foxesOnTheLine - количество лис в одной строке и столбце

    printf("\nВведите координаты клетки, в которую хотите выстрелить: ");
    if((scanf("%d%d", &coordinatesRow, &coordinatesCol) != 2) || (coordinatesRow <= 0) || (coordinatesRow > 8) || (coordinatesCol <= 0) || (coordinatesCol > 8))
        return 0;
    else {
        if(fieldForOutput[coordinatesRow-1][coordinatesCol-1] != ' ')   //проверка, ходили ли уже в эту клетку
            return 0;

        else {
            fieldForOutput[coordinatesRow-1][coordinatesCol-1] = 'X';
            foxes--;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int Win() {
    if(foxes == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;

}

int main() {

    char fieldForOutput[8][8];      //поле для вывода

    system("cls");
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
            fieldForOutput[i][j] = ' '; //заполнение поля пробелами

    while(Win() != 1) {     //цикл продолжается до тех пор, пока не будут убиты все лисы
        system("cls");
        if(InputSteps(fieldForOutput) == 0) {
            printf("Вы ввели некорректные данные!");
            _getch();
        }
    }

    system("cls");
    OutputField(fieldForOutput);
    printf("\nВы подстрелили всех лис!");
    return 0;
}
```

Функция как бы возвращает значение bool (в данном случае 0 или единицу) в зависимости оттого, правильно ли мы ввели данные.
И трабла с циклом: если мы попадаем в клетку, в которую уже ходили или выходим за пределы (меньше единицы или больше восьмерки), то все в порядке - выводится сообщение и функция вызывается сначала.
Но если не дай бог ввести букву (или буквы), то выходит сообщение "Вы ввели некорректные данные", а после нажатия любой клавиши программа выводит это сообщение еще раз и все зависает (скрин)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что при некорректном вводе он остается не считанным, и вы читаете его заново... Вам нужно сбросить введенное - в простейшем неаккуратном варианте - после `_getch()` сбрасывайте буфер ввода:

```
char buf[256];
fgets(buf,256,stdin);
```

Примерно так...

Answer (score 0):

Использовать функцию scanf() для считывание данных пользователя, не корректно. Пользователь может ввести различные данный. Лучше воспользоваться небольшими библиотеками вроде [ncurses](http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/) небольшая и простая.